# Why is a conditional formatting range mis-applying some cells?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet with one conditional formatting rule defined:
[image]

This is the *only* formatting rule in the sheet:
[image]

As you can see, Q3 is not obeying the rule. And when I test, neither is Q2. At some point I've inserted new rows at the top, but then I would expect my conditional formatting to show it is missing those cells and it's not.

What is wrong and how do I fix it? If it's not clear, the point is a whole row should be green if the Q cell is empty.

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: @doubleunary since the sheet was previously working, I wouldn't know how to reproduce it!

Comment: @doubleunary though possibly I could clone it and anonymise any sensitive data

Comment: That would help, so please do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional formatting custom formula rule should work OK. Since it fails to color rows where column `Q` appears blank, chances are are that column `Q` really contains something, for example a space character. Try this rule that will give `true` when column `Q` is blank or contains whitespace:

`=trim($Q1) = ""`

Comment: You have it backwards I think. It _is_ coloring row 3 when the cell definitely contains text (15/05/2021)

Comment: The rule will return `true` when the cell in column `Q` is blank or only contains whitespace, and `false` when it contains any visible value. Try it as a regular formula in cell `R1` to see how it works. When using it in a conditional format rule, make sure you apply the rule for a range that starts in row 1, such as `A1:Q`.

Comment: Remove other formatting rules you may have defined, or make them give a different color, so that you know which rule is coloring the cells.

Comment: As I said, this is the _only_ formatting rule